Instalación de ProcessMaker
Estoy instalando el Processmaker por proyecto de la Universidad pero al momento de instalar las dependencias de php 8.1 no me permite, llevo toda la noche intentando resolver este problema pero me sale los mismo siempre, aun que baje de version php o suba da el mismo error, ¿alguna solución?
     root@serv-VirtualBox:/opt/processmaker# sudo apt-get install
     php8.1=8.1.29-1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 php8.1-cli=8.1.29-
1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 php8.1-curl=8.1.29-
1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 php8.1-dom=8.1.29-
1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 php8.1-fpm=8.1.29-
1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 php8.1-gd=8.1.29-
1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 php8.1-json=8.1.29-
1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 php8.1-mbstring=8.1.29-
1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 php8.1-mysql=8.1.29-
1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 php8.1-simplexml=8.1.29-
1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 php8.1-tokenizer=8.1.29-
1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 php8.1-zip=8.1.29-
1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

            Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
            Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho
            Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
            El paquete php8.1-json es un paquete virtual provisto por:
              php8.1-phpdbg 8.1.29-1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
              php8.1-fpm 8.1.29-1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
              php8.1-cli 8.1.29-1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
              php8.1-cgi 8.1.29-1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
              libphp8.1-embed 8.1.29-1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
              libapache2-mod-php8.1 8.1.29-1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
            Necesita seleccionar explícitamente uno para instalar.
            
            El paquete php8.1-tokenizer es un paquete virtual provisto por:
              php8.1-common 8.1.29-1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
            Necesita seleccionar explícitamente uno para instalar.
            
            El paquete php8.1-dom es un paquete virtual provisto por:
              php8.1-xml 8.1.29-1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
            Necesita seleccionar explícitamente uno para instalar.
            
            El paquete php8.1-simplexml es un paquete virtual provisto por:
              php8.1-xml 8.1.29-1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
            Necesita seleccionar explícitamente uno para instalar.
            
            E: No se encontró la versión «8.1.29-1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1» para «php8.1-json»
            E: No se encontró la versión «8.1.29-1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1» para «php8.1-dom»
            E: No se encontró la versión «8.1.29-1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1» para «php8.1-simplexml»
            E: No se encontró la versión «8.1.29-1+ubuntu24.04.1+deb.sury.org+1» para «php8.1-tokenizer»
            root@serv-VirtualBox:/opt/processmaker#


¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de error/trazas de pila en imágenes, publica directamente el texto del código, el texto de los errores y los stack traces. Esto hace que sea menos complicado, para quien quiera ayudarte, investigar sobre el tema y hacer sus propias pruebas/adaptaciones al código, al escribir una respuesta y de esa forma aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.
